# WebGL in QuickLook

Tags: html, safari, webkit, webgl, quicklook

Is it possible to use WebGL in a quicklook plugin?

I followed this [tutorial](http://blog.10to1.be/cocoa/2012/01/27/creating-a-quick-look-plugin/) replacing the relevant code in `GeneratePreviewForURL.m` with

```
OSStatus GeneratePreviewForURL(void *thisInterface, QLPreviewRequestRef preview, CFURLRef url, CFStringRef contentTypeUTI, CFDictionaryRef options) {
    NSString *_content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:(__bridge NSURL *)url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSString* path = @"/Users/myusername/Downloads/TodoQL/demo.html";

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString* _html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
       error:&error];
   if(error) { // If error object was instantiated, handle it.
      NSLog(@"ERROR while loading from file: %@", error);
      }
    NSLog(@"\n%@\n",_html);
    QLPreviewRequestSetDataRepresentation(preview,(__bridge CFDataRef)[_html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],kUTTypeHTML,NULL);

    return noErr;
}

void CancelPreviewGeneration(void *thisInterface, QLPreviewRequestRef preview) {
    // Implement only if supported 
}
```

For debugging, this is set up to discard the contents of of the file quicklook is given and rather just render a local html file located at `/Users/myusername/Downloads/TodoQL/demo.html`.

I use [this barebones WebGL example](http://www.netmagazine.com/files/tutorials/demos/2011/07/get-started-with-webgl-draw-a-square/demo/demo.html), altering only slight to show that the gl context is not being loaded:

```
gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
if(!gl)
{
  document.body.innerHTML = ":-(";
  return;
}
```

Indeed, running `/usr/bin/qlmanage -p example.example` shows the disappointed face rather than the webgl demo.

In Safari, this demo works so long as I "Enable WebGL". Do I need to enable WebGL somehow for quicklook plugins? How?

Comment: The apple documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/Quicklook_Programming_Guide/Articles/QLDynamicGeneration.html) writes "Important: For security reasons, you cannot use Web Kit plug-ins in HTML passed back to Quick Look (so you cannot, for example, use Java applets, video, or Flash animations)." So, does this include webgl?

Comment: WebGL is not a plugin, so it wouldn't fall under that restriction. Safari, however, does not yet enable WebGL by default, a restriction that probably carries over to Quick Look. I doubt they provide a way to override it in that setting.

Comment: So there's this way to enable it for a `WebView` http://stackoverflow.com/a/13661279/148668 . But how can I get a `WebView` inside `GeneratePreviewForURL` for a quicklook extension?